# How can I connect and retrieve data from wamp server database in Android app ?

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I'm using Android Studio to create a job search app:

When users input keywords and press "Find" button, the app will connect to wamp server database to get related data and then display the result in list view. For example, an user type "web developer" and press Find button, job info which is related to web developer will be shown as a list view. 
How can I do that ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The answer to this question could fill a small book. Please try to narrow down your question. What have you tried and why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Go make an API. Tons of doc out there

Comment: I have searched for so long. I just found that there are so many tutorials regarding connecting to DB , retrieving data using PHP and then pass the data to Android app and show ALL the data as a listview... But, there are so little info which teaching how to filter the data and just show the wanted data instead of ALL. For example, I type "XXX" in the edit text box , and press a "search" button , and the result only shows the data related to XXX.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `JSON` request for your data and store it localy in `sqlite`. Then on search, just search the `table` for the keyword and show the 
`row` that have what you want. If you dont know what i am talking abou i recommend you start reading some documents or tutorials.

Comment: I successfully connect the database using php to grep all the data in the table of my DB, now I'm thinking of how to using the data grep from php and display it as listview in android app based on the search requirement typed by the users. Could you kindly help?  thanks.